# Sonata admin All elements it counts not all elements but how many page it has

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

This is default list view

[image]

Like we see - all elements - delete say - 16 but this is not true - deleting  concerns all filtered elements - so 32 in this situation.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

All means all in this case, not only the filtered ones

Comment: All means all , but couter show how many is visible on the page. So this is error yes ? And second - no all elements will be done on filtered results - so behavior is good. But description wrong.

Comment: If you filter down your results from 16 (=all) down to 8, and use "All elements" checkbox and delete-batch-action, then all 16 should be deleted afterwards.